# Display only those rows, whose SUM(price) is more than a certain number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

- customers(name, id),
- items(name, price, id),
- purchases(id,    items_id, customers_id)

When I run:

```
select 
 customers.name,
 SUM(items.price) as "price"
from items
INNER JOIN purchases
ON items.id = purchases.item_id
INNER JOIN customers
ON purchases.customer_id = customers.id
GROUP BY customers.name
ORDER BY "price"
```

This is the result that I get:

```
"Anne Watson" "5.00"
"Craig Scott" "11.30"
"Michael Adam" "101.29"
"Jose Salvatierra" "899.00"
"Rolf Smith" "1174.50"
```

However, ​I would like to only show those rows, which have price over 100 (3 bottom ones in this case). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you use a `HAVING` clause. It's similar to a `WHERE` clause, but applied after the `GROUP BY`.

```
HAVING SUM(items.price) > 100
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using having "price" >100. Which is an alias for sum(items.price) that I have created. Any idea why that did not work?

Comment: But "price" is an alias for aggregated function.

Comment: @Leo that's exactly what he wants.

Comment: @Eduard most platforms want you to reference the actual expression in HAVING(). If you have more than a couple, or if they are complex, you can code around this limitation by wrapping the query in a derived table or using a CTE.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA found out the reason behind that. It is because the "price" has not yet been created at the time we run HAVING. Here we only have a calculation with no alias assigned to it. The alias is being created at the end of the execution of the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only SUM(prices) greater than 100 include a HAVING clause as below.

```
select 
 customers.name,
 SUM(items.price) as "price"
from items
INNER JOIN purchases
ON items.id = purchases.item_id
INNER JOIN customers
ON purchases.customer_id = customers.id
GROUP BY customers.name
having sum(items.price) >100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the WHERE function

```
select 
   customers.name,
   SUM(items.price) as price
from items, purchases, customers
where 
   items.id = purchases.item_id and purchases.customer_id = customers.id and 
   items.price > 100

GROUP BY customers.name
ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It’s always a good idea to post an explanation along with any code snippets.